# C++ Ensure that subclasses provide a custom value for a constant

Tags: c++, inheritance

Assume we have an abstract `class A`, which has multiple subclasses. Each concrete class (not object) has a priority associated with it. One way of storing this priority is simply as a `protected int prio` in `A`.

But how do you ensure that each subclass indeed sets a value for `prio`?

The only way I can think of is using templatization and making the priority part of the type. I am hoping for a more lightweight approach.

Comment: are you thinking of a non-static member `prio` or of a static one?

Comment: class A should have a protected constructor that takes an int parameter (prio).

Comment: @ Richard Critten But how do you ensure that the prio is constant for each object of a class?

Comment: @Stephan Lechner  either way is fine, static is probably more appropriate

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Can you provide any code example for that?

Comment: Priority implies some sort of primacy of one subclass over another depending on the value of prio. Implantation will be dependent on where the priorities are decided.

Comment: @user695652 implement a protected constructor that sets a private member of the base class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a way that ensures that non-static data members are initialized in sublcasses. Maintaining different static data members with the same meaning is tricky and error prone, too. So I'd suggest to use a pure virtual function to get the subclasses' priority on the fly. Pure virtual ensures that the subclasses must override this getter:

```
class Base {
public:
    void print() const { std::cout << "prio: " << getPrio() << std::endl; }
protected:
    virtual int getPrio() const = 0;
};

class Sub1 : public Base {
    int getPrio() const override { return 1; }
};

class Sub2 : public Base {
    int getPrio() const override { return 2; }
};

int main()
{
    Sub1 s1;
    Sub2 s2;
    s1.print();
    s2.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use classic overriding. The priorities of same classes are always equals.

```
class A {
public:
  virtual int get_priority()=0;
};


class B : A {
public:
  int get_priority() {
     return 2;
  }
};

class C : A {
public:
  int get_priority() {
    return 3;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> One way of storing this priority is simply as a `protected int prio` in `A`.

That is not going to work.

If you use

```
static int prio;
```

You'll have only one variable for `A` and all of its sub-classes.

If you use

```
int prio;
```

each instance will have that as a member variable, defeating the purpose of create a value for each class.

You could use the following strategey to minimize boilerplate code.

```
class A { ... };

template <typename T>
struct PriorityHolder
{
   static int prio;
};

template <typename T> 
int PriorityHolder<T>::prio = <Find a suitable method for value>;

class Derived1 : public A,
                 public PriorityHolder<Derived1>
{
    ...
};
```